# Combining the forward and backward algorithms in HMMs

Tags: machine-learning, probability, hidden-markov-model, forward-backward

Suppose that I have a Hidden Markov Model and want to estimate the probability of a sequence of observations. Furthermore, not only do I wish to know the total probability of the sequence, but I want to be able to analyze the probability at every single time step.

How can I combine the Forward Algorithm and the Backwards Algorithm to effectively obtain a good estimate for every time step?

Comment: You're inventing the [forward–backward algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward–backward_algorithm).